# Node not installed after installation

Tags: node.js

I installed nodejs using `sudo apt-get`, which appeared to continue perfectly. 
If I now run `sudo apt-get install nodejs` it'll tell me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
```

Yet, when I try to test node using `node -v` or `node hello.js` there is no reply. No error nothing.

How can I get it running?

Comment: we can see that 0 new installed, you can install by following this instruction https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: @ArifKhan. I followed the instructions, now if I use `node -v` it'll return `node -v
-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove current nodejs package

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

and run the following command (node version 10)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

then check again

```
node -v
```